# mysql connector/mysqlclient and django issues on Windows

Tags: python, mysql, django, windows

I have installed `mysql connector` , which already has a built in sql adapter, i also don't need to install `mysqlclient` as i have mysql connector. But when i start python manage.py migrate, it is asking me to download mysqlclient. But i can not install `mysqlclient`. Can anyone help me how to fix the problem. Thanks

error:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 101, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 305, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 203, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 20, in <module>
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

Comment: I had two views when you made the changes, it was bit complicated so i had to reedit it.  However thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to install mysql-connector-c connector and after:

```
pip install mysqlclient==1.3.13
```

Comment: i receive an error :  can not satisfy the version requirement. i am using python 3.7.1 ,pip 18.0 and django 2.1.

Comment: Can you show your DATABASES settings from settings.py file ?

Answer (score 0):

[There are two backends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers) for using MySQL with python

- mysqlclient - recommended by the docs, but can be tricky to install on Windows
- mysql connector - doesn't always support the latest Django version.

First you need to decide which backend you want to use.

If you want to use mysql connector, then you don't need to install `mysqlclient`. You do need to change `ENGINES` in your `DATABASES` setting to use the connector backend.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'user_data',
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

If you make this change, it should stop the *did you install mysqlclient* error messages. See [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-django-backend.html) for more info about using mysql connector.

If you want to use `mysqlclient`, then leave the ENGINE as `'django.db.backends.mysql'` in your `DATABASES` setting. Installing `mysqlclient` on Windows can be tricky, you have a few different options:

1. Install an official wheel. As of December 2018, there are wheels for the latest release mysqlclient 1.3.14 for Python 3.6 and Python 3.7. Install mysqlclient with:

   ```
   pip install mysqlclient==1.3.14
   ```
2. Install one of the [unofficial wheels](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient). This will allow you to use Python 3.7 and a more up-to-date version of mysqlclient.
3. Install mysqlclient from source. This can be tricky on Windows, and I can't offer any tips on how to do that.